# How can i remove a member variable in javascript class?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple game in javascript 
similar to the android game "2 cars". [This](http://www.mediafire.com/view/pyrls805et55xhl/Capture.PNG) is a snapshot of what I did so far.

Here is my code:

```js
function leftRedcircleclass() //Left red circle class
{
    if (Math.random() * 170 < 85) {
        randLeft = 17;
    }
    else {
        randLeft = 105;
    }
    this.image = document.createElement("img");
    this.image.src = "leftredcircle.png";
    this.image.style.position = "absolute";
    this.image.style.left = randLeft + "px";
    this.image.style.top = 3 + "px";
    this.image.style.width = "3.5%";
    this.image.style.zIndex = 1;
    document.body.appendChild(this.image);
}

function RandomCreation()    
{
    noRedcircles = 0;
    noBluecircles = 0;

    int1 = setInterval(function () {  //red circles
        redCirclearray[noRedcircles] = new leftRedcircleclass();
        MoveDown(redCirclearray[noRedcircles].image);
        noRedcircles++;
    }, (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 1000));
}

function MoveDown(obj) //For moving the circles or the squares`
{
    var int = setInterval(function () {
        obj.style.top = parseInt(obj.style.top) + 1 + "px";
    }, 1);
}
```

I'd like to know how to remove the image of the circle giving a certain condition, for example when its top is equal to the car's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for code to remove the image from the DOM you need to use [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).  It's kind of weird, because you need to access the parent to remove the child node:

```
this.image.parentNode.removeChild( this.image );
```

### Edit:

You might also want to add a method to the image constructor, so that you can edit it after initializing it:

```
leftRedcircleclass.prototype.removeImage = function () {
    this.image.parentNode.removeChild( this.image );
};
```

and then remove it using the instance saved in the array:

```
redCirclearray[ index_of_image ].removeImage();
```

### Another Edit (fuller answer):

And remove the instance from the array:

```
redCirclearray.splice(index_of_image, 1);
```